# laravel 4 blade include more that one sub-view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

when i try insert more that one include inside the container just appears contacts.create sub-view i don't know why.

```
@extends('layout')

@section('container')
    @include('contacts.create')
    @include('products.create')
@stop
```

Just return contacts.create or the first @include. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do this?

```
@extends('layout')

@section('contacts')
    @include('contacts.create')
@stop

@section('products')
    @include('products.create')
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for including is fine, so my guess is you have syntax errors in your blade files which is causing the blade compiler to not return any content somewhere along the way.

1. Double check that the file you're trying to include includes blade in the name, i.e. located at: /products/create.blade.php
2. Try replacing the contents of products.create with a simple 
   `<p>this is products.create</p>`
   statement. If this displays fine you can work backwards from there and build your file up again to see what's causing it not to display.
3. You can also vardump the return statements from the blade compiler if you really want to see what's going on.

Go to the BladeCompiler.php file, and find compileIncludes function:
Add this before the return statement:

```
var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value));
```

just make sure you run composer dump-autoload after.

Also, are you currently seeing the contents from layout, or only from contacts.create?
If it only renders from contacts the issue could be in the layouts file instead.